# understanding a piece of code with ``boolean`` and ``switch``

Tags: processing.js

i was looking some examples of  interactions with the keyboard and stumbled upon this code that i found interesting. But i'm having trouble understanding a certain part of it(it's marked down below).I don't get how all this whole ''boolean'' declaration, ''switch'' and ''CASE'' works, i tried to look in the reference but still. Could someone explain in a simple maner how these work?

```
float x = 300;
float y  = 300;
float speed = 5;
boolean isLeft, isRight, isUp, isDown; 
int i = 0;

void keyPressed() {
  setMove(keyCode, true);

if (isLeft ){
  x -= speed;
}
if(isRight){
  x += speed;
}
}

void keyReleased() {
  setMove(keyCode, false);

}

boolean setMove(int k, boolean b) {// <<<---  From this part down
  switch (k) {
  case UP:
    return isUp = b;

  case DOWN:
    return isDown = b;

  case LEFT:
    return isLeft = b;

  case RIGHT:
    return isRight = b;

  default:
    return b;  }
}
```

Comment: Where are UP, DOWN, etc. defined?

Comment: @Cristina Please notice the [tag:processing.js] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these are best answered by [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/switch_/):

> Works like an `if else` structure, but `switch()` is more convenient when you need to select between three or more alternatives. Program controls jumps to the case with the same value as the expression. All remaining statements in the switch are executed unless redirected by a `break`. Only primitive datatypes which can convert to an integer (byte, char, and int) may be used as the expression parameter. The default is optional.

The rest of the code is setting the corresponding variable to whatever value you passed in as the `b` parameter, and then returning it.

You should get into the habit of [debugging](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code. Add print statements to figure out exactly what the code is doing.